# Managing Application height in WPF (Expressing height as a percentage of screen height)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, styles

So I created a WPF application on my monitor which has bigger height (1280 vs 1024) resolution. It is working fine on my monitor.

But when I take it to a monitor of different resolution the whole application extends beyond the monitor and as a result is not usable.

Any idea how we can rectify this. All the height of my controls and window height is fixed

Comment: Did you set window size in pixels?

Comment: @Vale: I used Height as units (Device Independent). It works great on my monitor but it doesnt work on smaller monitors. I will try out the approach in Matthew's answer

Comment: @Smudge: Sorry I didnt know that we had to mark the post as answer ourselves. I usually thank the poster in the comment. I went back and marked more answered questions

Comment: @ganeshran not to worry, I'm glad you've found it now.  Saying thanks is always nice too ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy. Reduce the height of your window. Why are you using a large fixed height window? Obviously I don't know the design of your application, but as you have quickly found out, fixed heights (and widths) tend not to be portable across different pieces of hardware.

The real solution for you is probably to use a WPF `Grid` control. All of your controls should be in the grid, which fills the entire window. Depending on how you set up your grid rows and columns, your controls will scale in size as the size of your window changes.

Say you have four controls you want evenly stacked in your grid. You could do this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height=".25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefintions>
    <MyControl Grid.Row="0"/>
    <MyControl Grid.Row="1"/>
    <MyControl Grid.Row="2"/>
    <MyControl Grid.Row="3"/>
</Grid>
```

Now each control takes 25% of the available space, and WPF handles everything as your window size changes. You can do much more complicated layouts than this, but hopefully this gets you started.

Comment: Hi Matthew - this is my mainwindow xaml 

Height="Auto"  Width="750"
        MaxWidth="750"
        Background="{DynamicResource MainBackgroundBrush}"
        MinWidth="700"
        MinHeight="800"

So shouldnt I set any height at all in the application?

Comment: I just found that I had set a minHeight. Maybe this was causing the problem. I removed it and going to test now.

Answer (score 1):

WPF wasn't really designed to be treated like WinForms, where by absolute control widths, heights, and positions cause these situations. It was designed to be fluid, allow controls to wrap (see [WrapPanel](http://www.wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html)), Expand and Collapse (see the Auto or * sizes). If you treat it like WinForms, you'll hit these problems and have to come up with complex workarounds. WPF was designed as the permanent solution to those complex workarounds (amongst other things)

Try looking for a basics tutorial for WPF, to get an idea of how the UI should be layed out.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Should I not enter anything in the height and width of the window? Will it automatically fill to the rest of the screen?

Comment: Do you need the application to fill the screen?  I tend to develop my WPF apps using the smallest screen space possible whilst the app is still useful. I set those dimensions as the minHeight and minWidth. Then expand your app to see how it resizes, ideally everything should grow proptionately and still maintain the look and feel you want for your application.  If you want to fill the screen, do the last two points, and then set your application to a Maximised Windowstate when the app starts.