# How to resize/control an already implemented and released WPF application's height

Tags: c#, wpf, window, height

I have built an application using c# and WPF. The application has been launched and the customers are using it. Now, this is the issue.

In my application, the window's minimum height has been set to 825 but the customer's screen resolution is 1366 (width) x 768 (height). Thus, the customer is not able to see the entire UI and thus, some buttons are not totally available for the user to use due to the minimum height issue.

I know I can reduce the minimum height and put an end to this but this would involved releasing the next update of the application right? Without doing this, how can I release a temporary fix to the users? A way to control the application's window minimum height property from an external way (say through a bat file or something).

Comment: Don't think it's possible.

Comment: sell a new screen to your customer :) or let him use snoop to edit the heigt on runtime. but i think its no solution for you.

Comment: haha :) that would totally change the company's vision and mission ;) so controlling a wpf application's UI outside the application seems unlikely. so, the way to go would be to modify the code and release the next update to the user in the form of an installer, right?

Comment: I've never tried it, but perhaps create a "wrapper" application that hosts your compiled application inside a `ScrollViewer` or `ViewBox`? Or figure out how [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) works and script something to automatically snoop the application and find the Window's MinHeight property and change it? Honestly it'd probably be easier to do a quick fix on the version they're on and let them use it until you're ready to release the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the * in the Height?  Auto will match this size of any controls however the * gives you the remainder that you can use with the Stretch

If you have more than one * definition then each one will be proportions

e.g.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="50" /> <!-- Header for Example
     <RowDefinition Height="*" /> <!-- Use Whatever space is left in the parent control
     <RowDefinition Height="50" /> <!-- Close Buttons etc
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

See [Managing Application height in WPF (Expressing height as a percentage of screen height)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663105/) for more info